# Active admin: Update the fields through CSV

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

How I can update and create a new data in a model through uploading the CSV file?

Is there any documentation for this?

Is there any method without using gem?

Comment: write an importer which uses csv data for creating Model's instances

Comment: I didn't use but you can try `gem "active_admin_import" , '2.1.2'`

Comment: Is it possible to update the data  using that gem @Pardeep

Comment: as i told i didn't use this gem , but you want some easy way so you can use this .